# How to rewrite these URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using a plugin to create and display domains I'm selling.

For each individual domain listed the plugin creates a single post.

The url of the single post is automatically generated as `/?mdlp_my_domain_list=znvr-com` where `znvr.com` is the domain for sale and title of the post.

What I would like is to clean up the url by removing `/?mdlp_my_domain_list=` and having it displayed as `/znvr-com`

I've looked inside the plugins php files, but can't seem to find what line of code is displaying the urls this way (only have basic php knowledge).

I think a simple htaccess rewrite is all I need to fix it, but nothing I've tried is working so far.

Any idea how I can fix this? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(index\.php)?\?mdlp_my_domain_list=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /?mdlp_my_domain_list=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok I added the code to the htaccess giving me: 
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(index\.php)?\?mdlp_my_domain_list=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /?mdlp_my_domain_list=$1 [L,QSA]

# END WordPress` 
Almost works, but gives a redirect loop 

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: They need to go before all your wordpress rules

Comment: I added it above all of the wordpress rules and I'm still getting a redirect loop. I think it has something to do with `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` and `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` being in the pre-existing rewrite rules.